# How to reference part of a theorem?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, counters

I have a corollary with a number of parts whose parts need to be referenced individually later on, so something like:

```
\begin{cor}\label{cor}
   \begin{enumerate}
       \item Part one \label{partone}
       \item Part two \label{parttwo}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{cor}
```

Ideally, I want `\ref{partone}` to produce 2.1 (supposing it were Corollary 2 for the sake of argument), but, of course, `\ref{partone}` gives 1, as it's referencing the `enumi` counter.

Is there a way to get `\ref` to somehow combine the `enumi` and `cor` counters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can also be achieved by using the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{cor}{Corolary}

\begin{document}

\begin{cor}\label{cor}
   \begin{enumerate}[label={\thecor.\arabic*}]
       \item Part one \label{partone}
       \item Part two \label{parttwo}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{cor}
As we see in part~\ref{partone}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[ref={\thecor.\arabic*}]`? I understand that holyland only wants the reference to be changed, not the label of the item itself.

Comment: @Michael Ummels: if the change should only affect the reference, then yes, `[ref={\thecor.\arabic*}]` would do the job; however, that would produce an odd result, since formally you would have a reference, for example, 1.2 to an object numbered as simply 2. For the sake of consistency I suggested the change to both the label and the reference.

Comment: I agree. Maybe, it is better to put the item number in parentheses, so the label would just say (1) and the reference would be e.g. to Theorem 2 (1). This could be done by saying `[label={(\arabic*)},ref={\thecor~(\arabic*)}]`, I suppose.

Comment: Michael's second suggestion is what I was after. We'll see what people say about consistency between labels and references (if anyone notices). My feeling is that having the labels appear as 2.1.1, 2.1.2, etc looks really cluttered, especially with 'Corollary 2.1' right above.

Answer (score 4):

i was going to ask the exact same question. i found the solutions given here too complicated, i especially didnt want to get new packages for such a simple job. so i kept on reading and i am now completely satisfied with this solution:

`\hyperref[partone]{\ref*{cor}.\ref*{partone}}`

Comment: This is great! Just to add some clarification to the answer: this command creates a reference and should be used where you'd normally put your `ref`. The `[partone]` tells you where the link should point to, the `\ref*{cor}` produces the number of the corollary and the `\ref*{partone}` produces the "subnumber" in the enumeration. You can also replace the first `\ref*` by `\cref*` to get something like "Corollary 2.1" automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/chngcntr) package to make the `enumi` counter depend on your `cor` counter.  If you do this within the corollary environment, it won't affect other enumerate environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\begin{cor}{My Cor}\label{mycor}
  \counterwithin{enumi}{cor}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item An item \label{part1}
    \item Another one \label{part2}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{cor}

In Part~\ref{part1} of the the corollary\ldots

\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item \label{outside}
\end{enumerate}
This is a reference to Item~\ref{outside} that is outside the corollary.
\end{document}
```

Even simpler, and without using the `chngcntr` package, you can simply redefine `\theenumi` within the `cor` environment:

```
\begin{cor}{My Cor}\label{mycor}
  \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thecor.\arabic{enumi}}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item An item \label{part1}
    \item Another one \label{part2}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{cor}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer: is there something wrong with the solution that I missed?

Comment: It does get the job done, as far as I can tell. I'm inclined to think Gonzalo's solution is more elegant or at least allows for more flexibility. (What I was actually after was Michael's comment to Gonzalo's answer.)

Comment: @hoyland I see. But since your question didn't actually state that...  Anyway, I don't particularly care about votes, (I certainly don't need the reputation) but you may want to take a look at this for some other ideas on downvoting: [Down Vote Etiquette](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/down-vote-etiquette)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't the down vote; I was just speculating. I have no idea what the objection could have been other than someone thinking it didn't answer the question, since people seemed to read it different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to slightly modify the approach with enuitem above. I am also going to make the following assumptions:

- All theorem-like environments have the same counter
- The counter is called \thethm

First I define a new list in the preabmle (after calling the enuitem package) called thmenum

```
\newlist{thmenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[thmenum, 1]{label=(\arabic*), ref=\thethm (\arabic*)}
```

So if you  have a theorem environment you can do this:

```
\begin{thm}
\label{thm:some_theorem}
\begin{thmenum}
  \item Statement 1\label{thm:some_theorem:somestatement}
  \item Statement 2\label{thm:some_theorem:someotherstatement}
\end{thmenum}
\end{theorem}
....
\ref{thm:some_theorem:somestatement}
```

will produce a reference of the form 1.1(1), but the labels will be (1), (2), ...