# How to label statements when you continuosly add/substract them over and over in a thesis?

Tags: cross-referencing

While writing a thesis, there are statements like *Corollary.5*, *Theorem.23*, etc. I refer these and sometimes, I am adding some extra statements between these referred ones so that the *Corollary.5* becomes *Corollary.6*. How to avoid these kind of problems?

Comment: I agree with aeismail, but it also sounds as if you're manually numbering things. If so, the solution is to make the computer do the work for you, using automated [cross referencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) [functionality](http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/theorems.pdf)

Comment: Migrating this to [tex.se] because it is purely about using a typesetting program and not specific to academia. Chances are that this is a duplicate, but I fail to find it (which justifies this question as it will make it easier to find the duplicate in the future).

Comment: Normally you would use `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` and similar environments to typeset theorems and the like. These environments can be set up to perform the numbering automatically. Then it is just a matter of setting a `\label` and referencing it later with `\ref`. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems (there are various packages for theorem labelling, but `amsthm` is one of the popular ones). There are fancy crossref packages such as `cleveref` that can automate this further.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I'm not sure this should have been migrated here from academia.SE; after all academics may use a number of document systems including (gasp) Word. So the question is not really specific to (La)TeX, though of course using LaTeX is the simplest *solution.*

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Initially the question posted on Academia was tagged LaTeX and BibTeX.

Comment: @moewe: That looks like it should be an answer.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13444/how-to-reference-part-of-a-theorem for example.